# GitPython not able to import Repo from Git

Tags: python, git

I am having a python script like below in a file git.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from git import  Repo

git_path = "test"

repo = Repo(git_path)

assert not repo.bare
```

Python version is : Python 2.7.12

OS : Description:   Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Gitpython - 2.1.7

I am getting the below error  when i run python git.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git.py", line 4, in <module>
    from git import  Repo
  File "/home/user/demo_files/git.py", line 4, in <module>
    from git import  Repo
ImportError: cannot import name Repo
```

I have checked most of the links ,available not able to resolve my issue.
Please help me.

Comment: You need to rename your script to something other than `git.py`.

Comment: I changed it to test2.py, stil lthe same issue.

Comment: you are correct i had my pyc file remaning in the fodler thats why it was not working . thank you

Answer (score 6):

Change your file name from git.py to othername  .py,
since your file is referring to itself it is throwing error